# Save data forever in JavaScript array from Input Tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, local-storage

I have a number coming from an `<input>`, that I would like to save in an array in a chosen place. I succeeded in doing it with `splice()`, but the data saved in array resets when the page is reloaded. How can I save that data *"forever"*?

This is the code:

```
<label for="number">Number to Save</label>
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" value=""/> 

<input type="button" value="click" onclick="myArr.splice(2, 0, number.value);"/>
```

Comment: You need to use some storage like Database or you can use localStorage check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: " the data saved in array resets when the page is reuploaded"...that's because web pages are stateless. The exist only for the time they are loaded into the browser. When you re-load the page, you're starting with a fresh copy, like the previous one never existed. As mentioned above, if you want to keep some data in between page re-loads, you need to use some storage - either something like localStorage in the browser, or, if the data must be shared between different users / browsers / devices, then server-side storage like a database.

Comment: But can't I save the data in a json, then convert json to array? Sorry for my stupid question, but I'm not good at JS

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple sample of using localStorage [http://jsfiddle.net/7e2o6ptw/](http://jsfiddle.net/nezir/Hn7jc/147/)

```
    // Retrieve your data from locaStorage
const saveData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("saveData") || null) || {};

// Store your data.
function saveStuff(obj) {
    saveData.obj = obj;

    const myArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
    console.log(myArr);
    saveData.some_array = myArr;

    console.log(saveData.some_array);
    saveData.some_array = myArr.splice(2);

    localStorage.setItem("saveData", JSON.stringify(saveData));
}

// Do something with your data.
function loadStuff() {
    return saveData.obj || "default";
}

if (saveData.some_array) alert("You were here: " + saveData.some_array);

saveStuff("Stuff");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not  store data forever. But you can store them in a cookie.

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

Read more about JS cookies :- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp